# How to auto delete revoked tokens by expiration date from database

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-passport

As suggested on the title, I'm using **Laravel Passport** and trying to figure out how to change some core functions so that when expire date hits a token, it gets removed from the database instead of having its revoked property true.

I don't really see the point in having old expired tokens in the database, but if there is a reason for that I would be thankful if you could enlighten me.

Comment: Why don't you run a cronjob nightly to clean them?

Comment: @Thomas could you please link documentation on how to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take a look at [Purge Tokens](https://laravel.com/docs/passport#purging-tokens)

You could handle it with this simple scheduled job:

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
    $schedule->command('passport:purge')->hourly();
}
```

Comment: This don't work for older laravel versions.